# css link element jumps on hover

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, element

I am trying to put a border around a link on hover, and the style applies to it, but it jumps (the element jumps) when i hover over it... what can I do?
     code:

```
  .navigation li:hover {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
 }
```

Comment: It's jumps because of adding border. To the left from elements appears left-border and elements goes to right for 1 px

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You 'jump' is caused by the 1px height of the border, that make your li move

You might use

```
 .navigation li:hover {
   border-color: #ccc;
 }

 .navigation li {
   border: 1px solid #<parentBackgroundColor/transparent>;
 }
```

instead. This way, the border is here from the beginning, so no jump on hovering, and it's invisible, since it's the same color of the parent container or transparent.

Comment: +1 for the solution - but a slight modification on the answer - set the border in .navigation li as suggested by @Clement Harreman, but in .navigation li:hover, only change the border-color. It aids inheritance a little.

Answer (score 9):

```
.navigation li {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

You can add a transparent `border` when you're not hovering, then it won't jump.

Or, you can remove a total of `2px` vertical `padding` around the element, for example:

```
.navigation li {
    padding: 10px
}
.navigation li:hover {
    padding: 9px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: @Laura Rafferty: The original answer's CSS was correct. If an element currently has `padding: 10px`, setting (on hover) `padding: 9px` will set `padding-top` from `10px` to `9px` and `padding-bottom` from `10px` to `9px` - for a combined reduction of `2px`.