# anchor tag acting different than button

Tags: html, css, hover, anchor

I have a list containing mainly buttons but also one anchor.

**Edit:** Each button/anchor **has a 1px border in its non-hover state**

**When I hover** over any `<li>` I add a **2px rounded corner** to the `<a>` or `<button>`

In order that the `<li>`'s don't 'jump' on hover I set width,height of `<li>` 4px more than the button/anchor

I have set `display:block` on anchor.

Why does my `<a>` element look different than the `<button>` ?

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/zpvzj/2/)**

Even if I add the following to fix the alignment of the anchor:

```
a.btn:before {
    content: '';
    margin-top: 14px;
}
```

(**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/zpvzj/3/)**)

...I still get the hover 'jumping effect on the anchor.

How can I fix this?

### Markup

```
<ul class="choices">
    <li class="source">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="source">
        <button type="button" class="btn">Btn1</button>
    </li>
    <li class="source">
        <button type="button" class="btn">Btn2</button>
    </li>
    <li class="source">
        <button type="button" class="btn">Btn3</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
*
{
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: yellow;
}
a, button /*reset default styles */
{
    margin:0;padding:0;border:0;
    background:transparent;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    line-height: normal;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.choices{
    text-align: justify;
}
.choices:after{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.source{
    width: 122px;
    height: 112px;
    display:inline-block;
}   
.btn{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #faf9fa;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    width: 118px; /* to take into account the 2px border on hover - */
    height: 108px; /* I make the button a little smaller than the li */
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #111; 
    float:left; 
    display:block;
    text-align: center; /*needed for the <a> tag  */
}
.btn:hover {
    border: 2px solid #952262;
    background: #f4f4f4;
}
.btn:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/50x50) no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5578686/1524085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 1px padding to the normal state, and remove it again in the hover state:

```
.btn{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #faf9fa;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    width: 118px; /* to take into account the 2px border on hover - */
    height: 108px; /* I make the button a little smaller than the li */
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #111; 
    float:left; 
    display:block;
    text-align: center; /*needed for the <a> tag  */
    padding: 1px; /** Set it here **/
}
.btn:hover {
    border: 2px solid #952262;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 0; /** Unset it here **/
}
```

Comment: +1 this seems to work, any idea about why the anchor is mis-behaving in the first place?

Comment: It's pretty straight-forward, you're just offsetting the difference in border sizes with padding. Of course if your padding changes, you'll need to compensate for that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without getting into why is your code wrong, the easiest way to fix it is to add a transparent border to your .btn class

```
.btn{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #faf9fa;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    width: 118px; /* to take into account the 2px border on hover - */
    height: 108px; /* I make the button a little smaller than the li */
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #111; 
    float:left; 
    display:block;
    text-align: center; /*needed for the <a> tag  */
    border:2px solid transparent;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qcw3B/)

Comment: This won't do because I am already using a border in the non-hover state

Comment: Borders widths on default and hover states should always be the same, it's just good practice because the border width has impact on layout. If you need something that mimics a border without impacting layout, use box-shadow. Something like: box-shadow:0 0 1px 1px #dcdcdc;

Comment: If you could update your fiddle to get it to work according to my requirements with box-shadow - that would be a good answer

Comment: I used red color for the shadow, since I can't really see the difference with the gray one - http://jsfiddle.net/qcw3B/

Comment: Yes, but you still have border: 2px solid transparent; on the anchor - I need a 1px border on the non-hover state

Answer (score 0):

Check this Update **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpvzj/5/)**

actually i added some border to `.btn` and `a.btn` and there hover state

Comment: Thanks, but this won't do because I am already using a 1px border in the non-hover state

Comment: Yes but you didn't write the individual code for a.btn .. anyways right now the fiddle i sent you seems working with no jumping effect..

Comment: You replaced my 1px border with a 2px border on the anchor

Comment: Oh, so you wanted to have 1px border on non-hover state and 2px border on hover state ?

Comment: Yes, that's my design requirements