# How to create a CSS hover; over the li tag with border, flicked?

Tags: html, css

I want to apply selected li a border, but seems hovering have a problem of flickering. Tried box-sizing still can't solve it.

```
li {
  background: red;
}

li:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Am I missing something?

https://jsfiddle.net/wf0r2c5q/1/

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625812/css-hover-border-makes-inline-elements-adjust-slightly and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612758/add-a-css-border-on-hover-without-moving-the-element and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578606/css-link-element-jumps-on-hover and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556153/inline-elements-shifting-when-made-bold-on-hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially set the `border-color` to `transparent` and on `:hover` state set `border-color` to your choice

***Stack Snippet***

```css
li {
  background: red;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

li:hover {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

...or another solution is use `box-shadow` `inset` instead of border

```css
li {
  background: red;
}

li:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0 0px blue inset, 0px -1px 0 0px blue inset;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is slick, the second option is much better! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add a `border: 1px solid transparent` to the `li` state.

```
li {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

It is flickering because a border changes the layout of the element.

Comment: I want to apply border for selected li, setting this means I can't apply border anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a  border: `1px solid red` or `1px solid transparent` on the `li` tag. The flickering you see is because you pass to 0px border to a 1px border

Answer (score 0):

I assume by 'flickering' you're talking about the slight change in position of the bullet point when you hover over the inner **[`<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)**. This is due to the fact that when you add your border, it shifts the bullet points down the page.

You can compensate for this by adding **[`margin: -1px auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)** to your **[`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)** state:

```css
li {
  background: red;
}

li:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: -1px auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: still flick if you look at it properly. and I want top and bottom border.